# CSS: Get every element inside a <p> and assign it a value?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a defined style:

```
#style p {
    padding:10px;
}
```

I do not know what elements will be inside the p. Is there a way to say that all elements inside that p should also have padding of 10px? Something like:

```
#style p everything {
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Please utilize a search engine, before asking questions. BTW: You can't assign a value to an element via CSS. You want to assign the value to the CSS property.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the universal selector `*`

```
#style p * 
{
    padding:10px;
}
```

It literally stands for "everything" so this selector will select any and all elements within your p. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Used to this**

```
#style p * {
    padding:10px;
}
```